# Euler's Totient with primes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know how to solve for phi if a number has prime factorization, but how do you do it with a prime number? for eg, 13
.

Comment: For all primes $p$ you simply have $\varphi(p)=p-1$

Comment: oh, why is that?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Euler totient function?

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Euler's totient function counts how many natural numbers less than $n$ are coprime to $n$, so if $n$ is prime, there are how many of these?

Comment: The prime factorization of a prime is the prime itself

Comment: [This might help you (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your formula, you likely know that $$\phi(p^n) = p^n (1-1/p) = p^n-p^{n-1}$$
Thus $\phi(p) = \phi(p^1) = p^1-p^0=p-1$.

However, it is much easier to use the other definition, the $\#$ of relatively prime numbers to $p$ in the range $[1,p-1]$. All of these are relatively prime as $p$ is prime, and so $\phi(p) = p-1$

Answer (score 1):

Since $ \phi (n) $ denotes the number of integers x in the range $ 1 \leq x \leq n $ such that x and n are coprime and the definition of a prime number $p$ is that it's coprime with every $ x $ in the range of $ 1,...,p-1$.

So $ \phi (p) = p-1$, if p is a prime.